# Javascript JSON.parse expected parameter problem

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, parsing, ecmascript-6

JSON.parse expects a text as the first parameter as described in this page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse.

`JSON.parse(['["asd"]'])` result is `["asd"]`. Is this a bug?

Comment: Most of the builtin functions (maybe all?) convert arguments automatically to the expected data type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`JSON.parse` expects you to pass it a string.

You are passing it an array.

The array gets implicitly converted to a string using its `toString` method.

This flattens all the values inside it (all one of them) into a single string.

```js
const array = ['["asd"]'];
const string = "" + array;
console.log(string);
```

Comment: this implicit conversion is documented somewhere?

Comment: [Step 1 of the JSON.parse spec](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#sec-json.parse)

Comment: Thanks, also the polyfill suggested by MDN does `text = String(text);`

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because of the the combination of [Type coercion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Type_coercion) (implicit as stated before me) and the result of [Array.prototype.toString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toString).